# Spotipy - Listing only track and artists names in a playlist

Tags: python-3.x, spotify, spotipy

Hello All and thank you in advance for your help :)

Can someone help me understand how I can take the below code, which displays data for a specified playlist, and have it only show the artist and track names? I have been toying around with the API documentation for several hours and I have not been able to make heads or tales of it. Right now when it displays data it gives me a whole bunch of data in a jumbled mess. Also, note that I put dummy values in the client_id and Secret parts of this code.

```
from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyClientCredentials
import spotipy
import json


PlaylistExample = '37i9dQZEVXbMDoHDwVN2tF'

cid = '123'
secret = 'xyz'


auth_manager = SpotifyClientCredentials(client_id=cid, client_secret=secret)
sp = spotipy.Spotify(auth_manager=auth_manager)




playlist_id = 'spotify:user:spotifycharts:playlist:37i9dQZEVXbJiZcmkrIHGU'
results = sp.playlist(playlist_id)
print(json.dumps(results, indent=4))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would something like this be useful?:

```py
print("Song - Artist - Album\n")

for item in results['tracks']['items']:
    print(
        item['track']['name'] + ' - ' +
        item['track']['artists'][0]['name'] + ' - ' +
        item['track']['album']['name']
    )
```

Your output will look similar to this:

```
Song - Artist - Album

ONLY - ZHU - ONLY
Bad - 2012 Remaster - Michael Jackson - Bad 25th Anniversary
Orion - Rodrigo y Gabriela - Rodrigo y Gabriela
Shape of You - Ed Sheeran - ÷ (Deluxe)
```

Alternatively, you could create your own structure based on the returned one by Spotify but just keeping what you need:

```py
result_dict = {
    'tracks': {
        'items': [],
        'limit': 100,
        'next': None,
        'offset': 0,
        'previous': None,
        'total': 16
    },
    'type': 'playlist',
    'uri': '<playlist_uri>'
}
```

And your track structure that goes inside `'items'` from above:

```py
track_dict = {
    'track': {
        'album': {
            'name': item['track']['album']['name'],
        },
        'artists': [{
            'name': item['track']['artists'][0]['name'],
        }],
        'name': item['track']['name'],
    }
}
```

Then iterate and insert one by one:

```py
for item in results['tracks']['items']:
    track_dict = {
        'track': {
            'album': {
                'name': item['track']['album']['name'],
            },
            'artists': [{
                'name': item['track']['artists'][0]['name'],
            }],
            'name': item['track']['name'],
        }
    }
    # Append the track dict structure to your results dict structure
    result_dict['tracks']['items'].append(track_dict)
```

Having this as a result when printing `result_dict`:

```py
{
  'tracks': {
    'items': [{
      'track': {
        'album': {
          'name': 'ONLY'
        },
        'artists': [{
          'name': 'ZHU'
        }],
        'name': 'ONLY'
      }
    }, {
      'track': {
        'album': {
          'name': 'Bad 25th Anniversary'
        },
        'artists': [{
          'name': 'Michael Jackson'
        }],
        'name': 'Bad - 2012 Remaster'
      }
    }, {
      'track': {
        'album': {
          'name': 'Rodrigo y Gabriela'
        },
        'artists': [{
          'name': 'Rodrigo y Gabriela'
        }],
        'name': 'Orion'
      }
    }, {
      'track': {
        'album': {
          'name': '÷ (Deluxe)'
        },
        'artists': [{
          'name': 'Ed Sheeran'
        }],
        'name': 'Shape of You'
      }
    }],
    'limit': 100,
    'next': None,
    'offset': 0,
    'previous': None,
    'total': 4
  },
  'type': 'playlist',
  'uri': '<playlist_uri>'
}
```